# remove a programmatically added UIImageView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, removeall

i'm making a program that has 2 Buttons in main view ;

one is called show and other one is hide,

when user presses show butoon an imageview gets added to screen

code :

```
-(IBAction)show{
  UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 155, 155)];
  img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:img];
}
```

and when user presses the hide button , i want app to hide the image that  has been just added (img)

but...

when i use

```
-(IBAction)add{
  [img removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Xcode says "img Undecleared"

edit : Some said define the object as a public object (@property) but problem is that  the imageview gets added just once. but i wanted it to add new imageview every time user presses the Show button,

so i used the [[self subviews]objectAtIndex:xx]removeFromSuperview] method to solve the problem

Comment: Here you get this error because you not define the img for whole class  here you can acces this variable within a method of show because this variable scope is limited to the show method

Answer (score 7):

Set a `tag` for your image view & then you can get it by this tag.

```
[img setTag:123];

...

[[self.view viewWithTag:123] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: /Users/PoriaX/Desktop/toMake/Classes/toMakeViewController.m:16:0 /Users/PoriaX/Desktop/toMake/Classes/toMakeViewController.m:16: warning: 'UIView' may not respond to '-removeFromSuperView'

Comment: @user1846654 oh, it's `removeFromSuperview`, not `removeFromSuperView`.

Comment: FYI - Xcode 12, in the year 2021 - this solution still works when the HIDDEN toggle to YES magically stops working (I have multiple view controllers - working in 1, won't in the 2nd). Thanks again, @Kjuly

Answer (score 3):

Create object of `UIImageView` in `.h` file like bellow..

```
UIImageView *img;
```

and in `.m` file `viewDidLoad:` method just add it like bellow..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ///your another code
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 155, 155)];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    img.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:img];
}
```

and when show button press show the image

```
-(IBAction)show{
    img.hidden = NO;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:img];
}
```

and for hide just hide like bellow..

```
-(IBAction)add{
    img.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Paras definitely has it the right way.  You can put the `UIImageView *img` in `{ }` after your interface like this: `@interface ClassName { UIImageView *img; }` or as a property like this `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *img;` and reference `img` with `self.img`.

Comment: @KKendall yes dude you are right also but i use simple flow because user want to hide and show the image with click button only otherwise your logic is also right dude... Thanx.. :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just didn't understand the difference between the two, I actually just asked a question about that here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Make this UIImageView a member of your UIViewController class

Comment: any tutorial on this subjecT?

Answer (score 0):

your img object is visible in only show method not outside..thats why. Declare it outside and your problem will be solved.

Comment: no set it as @property or as a global variable just beneath the #import statements.